# How to stop popup if selectedItem is null

Tags: c#, .net, oop, methods, popup

How to stop program when `selectedItem` is null? I want to stop program because Show method return me `selectedItem` as null and I got empty in my List. I just want to stop program if `selectedItem` is null?

```
public static string Show(IList<ListItem> items, string title)
{
    ItemsPopupWindow instance = new ItemsPopupWindow(items, title);
    instance.ShowDialog();
    if (instance.selectedItem == null)
    {

    }
    return instance.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "stop program"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "close" the program or stop it. Id just do this.

```
string retVal = Foo.Show('YourList', 'YourTitle');
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
{
    // if you have a wpf application
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();

    // if you have a winforms application
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: It's doesn't work because I must have RETURN parameter

Comment: would it be a better idea to catch the null on whatever is calling this? What does that code look like?

Comment: I edited the answer to show what i think the calling code might look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can `throw` an exception.

```
public static string Show(IList<ListItem> items, string title)
{
    ItemsPopupWindow instance = new ItemsPopupWindow(items, title);
    instance.ShowDialog();
    if (instance.selectedItem == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The selected item is null.");
    }
    return instance.SelectedItem;
}
```

This will stop the execution of this method.  The calling method can have a `try`/`catch` block that can handle this.  If the calling method does not handle this thrown exception by catching it, it will go to the method that called that method.  If no method ever handles it, the program will crash.

```
public static void Main() {
    try {
         Show(new List<ListItem>(), "");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Console.Write("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/